# When does there exist a faithful normal expectation onto von Neumann subalgebra (finite vNa)?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Let $R$ be a finite von Neumann algebra and $S$ be a von Neumann subalgebra of $R$. What conditions must $S$ satisfy so that a faithful normal conditional expectation $\Phi : R \to S$ exists?

For instance, from [*Conditional expectations in von Neumann algebras*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123672900043), Takesaki (1972) , a sufficient condition is that $S$ be a maximal abelian self-adjoint subalgebra of $R$. The center of $R$ is definitely another candidate for such a subalgebra with the expectation given by the center-valued trace.

Is there a nice and complete characterization of such subalgebras?

Comment: If $R$ has separable predual (which it is usual to assume) then $R$ admits a faithful normal trace.  Construct in the usual way $L^2(R)$ with $L^2(S)$ as a subspace.  It is standard that the orthogonal projection $L^2(R)$ to $L^2(S)$ restricts to give a conditional expectation from $R$ to $S$.  So the answer is "always".  (This can also be seen from Takesaki's more general result: if $R$ has a faithful finite trace then its restriction to $S$ is obviously semifinite).

So are you really meant to be asking about the non-separable case?